# FreeBSD 10.1 - Postgis 2.1.4 /usr/bin/ld: //lib/libm.so.5: invalid DSO for symbol

Tags: postgis

Trying to install Postgis21 from port or Postgis 2.1.4 from Source on FreeBSD 10.1 (worked fine on 9.1) but keep getting the following:

/usr/bin/ld: //lib/libm.so.5: invalid DSO for symbol `cos@@FBSD_1.0' definition
//lib/libm.so.5: could not read symbols: Bad value

Postgis Ticket:  http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3003#comment:13
FreeBSD Ticket:  https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=195483

Make install clean from port version 21

pastebin.com/hALMbGvD

From Source Version 2.1.4 - CONFIGURE:

pastebin.com/c7rvbuFk

From Source Version 2.1.4 - MAKE

pastebin.com/LHfTHxJV

Any help greatly appreciated - this is driving me crazy.

Martin

Answer (score 2):

If libm was not explicitly linked in the Makefile, try adding -lm to your link flags.

I also recently upgraded from FreeBSD 10.0 to 10.1, and my application produced the same error  while linking.

Comment: -lm fixed this for me in another project.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I ended up doing a fresh install on a 32-bit system (because I had the chassis) of FreeBSD 9.3.  I installed Postgres 9.3 and then installed Postgis21.  It went off without a hitch!

There was definitely an issue with either the upgrade from 9.1 to 10.1 or an issue with 10.1 period.  Anyways, I'm glad it's working now!!

It's possible there's some form of linker issue but I toyed on this for weeks. Fresh install did the job.  I will wait until 10.x is more mature before trying this again.

Martin